# Trigger javascript fucntion when ShowToastEvent popup is closed

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to fire another javascript method when the ShowToastEvent popup is closed?

Here is the code I have that trigger the toast event:

```
          updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(

                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Event Message',
                        variant: 'success',
                        mode: 'sticky'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error Message',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
```

What I would like to have happen is when the Success popup 'X' is click another JS method would be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is native support of what you are looking for. The best you can do so far with [toasts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) is show some clickable links which would redirect you to certain record or webpages.

You have to re-invent the wheel and implement complete toast functionality yourself using [SLDS Toast.](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/)

Comment: Oof that's what I was kind of expecting. The link to the Lightning Design System page is super helpful though, so thanks for that!